# Connect Google Photos to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

Google Drive Settings list an option to "Create a Google Photos folder."  Checking it proposes to "Automatically put your Google Photos into a folder in My Drive."  I want to do this, but whenever I check that box and click Done (or anything else in that Settings pane) it will uncheck itself and the feature does not appear.

How do I enable this feature?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This may be directly related to the latest Drive/Photos update that up to this day wasn't fully rolled out - **https://www.blog.google/products/photos/simplifying-google-photos-and-google-drive/**

A recommended course of action is to wait a few more days until the update has been completed.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to check that anymore because Google Drive And Google Photos stopped being in Sync from July 10 2019. That checkbox is just the front-end residue of the old feature which probably will be removed in the upcoming days.

See Google Announcement: https://support.google.com/photos/answer/9316089

Answer (score 1):

That feature is no longer available, so the checkbox you're trying to use will probably disappear soon.

Comment: Do you have any reference to indicate the elimination of that feature?  Is it being replaced with any similar functionality?

Comment: @feetwet https://support.google.com/photos/answer/9316089